# The table designed in tablegenerator does not match when I export the code to overleaf

Tags: tables, color, longtable, landscape

I'm making a series of landscape tables in latex, but what I generate doesn't correspond to what I code.

I use the tablegenerator program to design the tables more easily.
What I'm doing is this:
[image]

the generated code is:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
% \usepackage{lscape}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ll|lll|}
\cline{3-5}
 &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 9: Aristóteles y el movimiento}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{F88379} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Recursos\\ didácticos\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fenómenos ópticos cotidianos: https://webs.ucm.es/info/gioq/fenopt/index.htm\\  Dioptrio plano 1 (GeoGebra): https://www.geogebra.org/m/d8ajchey\#material/nJgXqHZr\\  Dioptrio plano 2 (GeoGebra): https://www.geogebra.org/m/d8ajchey\#material/XaXAryMB\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{F88379} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{AC}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lectura: Lentes. Capítulo 39 de White, H. (2009). Física Moderna. Madrid: Limusa. \\  Ejercicios de la Olimpiada de Física.\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{F88379} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{Lecturas}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{F88379} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{PL}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}Propagación rectilínea de la luz y formación de imágenes con lentes convergentes.} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{E66771} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{C.C.}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{C.E.}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{Saberes}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{C.E}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E66771}\textbf{O.D}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{F88379} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}} & X & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}X} & \cellcolor[HTML]{F88379} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
\rowcolor[HTML]{F88379} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}CD,\\ CP\end{tabular}}} & X & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}D.1.1. Empleo del razonamiento lógico-matemático y la experimentación para interpretar y describir\\ las variables cinemáticas desde un punto de vista vectorial, en función del tiempo en los distintos\\  movimientos que puede tener un objeto, con o sin fuerzas externas, para resolver situaciones \\ relacionadas con la física en la vida diaria.\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}X} & \cellcolor[HTML]{F88379} \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{F88379} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{F88379} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{F88379} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}D.1.2. Análisis de las variables que influyen en un movimiento rectilíneo o circular, comparando \\ las magnitudes empleadas y sus unidades, para establecer conclusiones sobre los movimientos \\ cotidianos que presentan estos tipos de trayectoria.\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}} & \multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F88379}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}15\\ 16\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Falta centrar muchas cosas. Es para ver lo que ocupa}
\label{optica geometrica}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

and the generated image is
[image]
I have all the packages that indicate in the preamble, but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

The normal `tabular` environment in LaTeX is really not powerful enough for this kind of tables. And therefore `tablesgenerator` can't generate good code for them either.

I recommend using the `tblr` environment from the `tabularray` package for this. It can generate this table correctly, but writing it manually is a painstaking process. However, once you have one, it can more easily be adapted for future similar tables.

The site https://www.latex-tables.com/v3/index.html purports to be able to generate `tabularray` code, but I haven't tried it. It is still in alpha phase. I don't know if there are other table generators that can do this.

Anyway, here is a hand-built version of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{E66771}{HTML}{E66771}
\definecolor{F88379}{HTML}{F88379}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={ c c X l l },
    vspan=even,
    vlines, hlines,
    hline{1,1}={0pt}, vline{1,1}={0pt},
    rowsep={5pt},
    row{1}={E66771},
    row{2-5}={F88379},
    row{6}={E66771,font=\bfseries},
    row{7-10}={F88379},
}
  \SetCell[c=2]{c,white} & & \SetCell[c=3]{c,E66771} \textbf{UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 9: Aristóteles y el movimiento} \\
%
  \SetCell[c=2]{c,font=\bfseries,bg=E66771} {Recursos\\didácticos} & & \SetCell[c=3]{l} {Fenómenos ópticos cotidianos: https://webs.ucm.es/info/gioq/fenopt/index.htm\\
  Dioptrio plano 1 (GeoGebra): https://www.geogebra.org/m/d8ajchey\#material/nJgXqHZr\\
  Dioptrio plano 2 (GeoGebra): https://www.geogebra.org/m/d8ajchey\#material/XaXAryMB} & & \\
%
  \SetCell[c=2]{c,font=\bfseries,bg=E66771} {AC} & & \SetCell[c=3]{l} {Lectura: Lentes. Capítulo 39 de White, H. (2009). Física Moderna. Madrid: Limusa. \\  Ejercicios de la Olimpiada de Física.} & & \\
%
  \SetCell[c=2]{c,font=\bfseries,bg=E66771} {Lecturas} & & \SetCell[c=3]{l} & & \\ 
%
  \SetCell[c=2]{c,font=\bfseries,bg=E66771} {PL} & & \SetCell[c=3]{l} {Propagación rectilínea de la luz y formación de imágenes con lentes convergentes.} & & \\
%
  C.C. & C.E. & \SetCell{c} Saberes & C.E. & O.D. \\
%
  \SetCell[r=2]{l} {CD,\\CP} & X  & \SetCell[r=2]{bg=white} {D.1.1. Empleo del razonamiento lógico-matemático y la experimentación para interpretar y describir las variables cinemáticas desde un punto de vista vectorial, en función del tiempo en los distintos movimientos que puede tener un objeto, con o sin fuerzas externas, para resolver situaciones relacionadas con la física en la vida diaria.} & X & \SetCell[r=4]{m} {15\\16} \\
                          & X & & X & \\
%
  \SetCell[r=2]{l} &   & \SetCell[r=2]{bg=white} {D.1.2. Análisis de las variables que influyen en un movimiento rectilíneo o circular, comparando las magnitudes empleadas y sus unidades, para establecer conclusiones sobre los movimientos cotidianos que presentan estos tipos de trayectoria.} & &  \\
                          & & & & \\
%
\end{tblr}

\caption{Falta centrar muchas cosas [no más]. Es para ver lo que ocupa}
\label{optica geometrica}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, the `multirow` and `graphicx` packages aren't needed in this solution.